# How to drop missing dbf in recovering instance

Tags: linux, oracle11g, enterprise, dataguard

Colleague (really!) attempted to create a dbf on primary prod DG instance. This worked (though file subsequently dropped), but db_file_convert not set up for file location secondary so creation failed and "Missing" dbf created in $OH/dbs.

Errors in alert log:

```
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/<path>/<file>.dbf'
ORA-27054: NFS file system where the file is created or resides is not mounted with correct options
Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied
File #1124 added to control file as 'UNNAMED01124'.
Originally created as:
'/<path>/<file>.dbf'
Recovery was unable to create the file as:
'/<path>/<file>.dbf'
MRP0: Background Media Recovery terminated with error 1274
Errors in file /<path>/trace/<instance>_pr00_33046.trc:
ORA-01274: cannot add datafile '/<path>/<file>.dbf' - file could not be
created
```

This then causes DG on HA instance to fail with:

> ORA-01111: name for data file 1124 is unknown - rename to correct file
>
> ORA-01110: data file 1124: '/$OH/dbs/UNNAMED'
>
> ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 1124 - see DBWR trace file
>
> ORA-01111: name for data file 1124 is unknown - rename to correct file
>
> ORA-01110: data file 1124: '/$OH/dbs/UNNAMED'

File does not exist in prod and reading regarding non-recovering DG databases states to create file or drop it. Neither of these options are available in the secondary database. What are my options? Recreate control file on HA without ref to missing file then restart? Doesn't help that my DG knowledge is a tad rusty - by tad I mean solid iron oxide.

Answer (score 0):

Copied control file from source where missing file did not exist